# “ERROR 429: Too Many Requests.” occurs when using wget to download big file (15G) from Zenodo

Tags: linux, wget, zenodo

I want download the LoDoPaB-CT dataset from Zenodo from [here](https://zenodo.org/record/3384092#.YMhsRHUzYUF).

[image]

The 'test' and 'validation' data have been successfully downloaded. But when downloading the train data, which are very large. I always get the error `ERROR 429: Too Many Requests` after starting download sometime. That's to say when the download size is about 1G~3G, the 429 error occurrs. What should I do to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try to use "--wait" and "--continue" options of wget. For example:

```
wget --wait 10 --random-wait --continue ${your_url}
```

Will wait a random of 5 to 15 seconds between retrievals, and resume getting a partially-downloaded file.

Comment: Why use both `--wait 10` and `--random-wait`

Comment: `--random-wait` is based upon wait value: A random value between {0.5 * WAIT} and {1.5 * WAIT} seconds